# Does QBFC work with QuickBooks Server Database Manager

Tags: quickbooks, qbfc

I've tried looking all over intuit's site and have not managed to find an answer to this question.

I need to know if and how you can use the QBSDM with QBFC. As currently, it does not seem to work for me like it does if I'm just pointing at a company file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any QuickBooks integrated application, you MUST have QuickBooks installed on the computer that the SDK/integrated application is installed on. You will *always* point your integrated app at the QuickBooks company file, regardless of what sort of environment/client-server set up you're running.

The Server Database Manager has no effect what-so-ever, and has literally *nothing* to do with integrated applications - it is completely irrelevant.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was coming up with in my research. I appreciate the second.